# Не могу попасть в контейнер docker с jupyter через веб-интерфейс

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

Я установил Docker собрал и запустил на нём контейнер с Jupyter-notebook командой `docker run -t image:1` и получил в результате ссылку на веб-интерфейс контейнера: `http://50951bff15f7:8765/`. Если я запускаю Jupyter без докера, то получаю ссылку вида: 
`http://localhost:8888/?token=43280a5fe388fcc8149154e925560322787547af299905e3`
Далее ввожу token в веб-интерфейсе и работаю.
Но Jupyter из докера даёт ссылку без токена. Соответственно я захожу на веб-интерфейс. Вижу требование о вводе пароля, но ни пароля, ни токена у меня нет. Что делать?
В докере по которому собирался образ запуск Jupyter выглядит так:

```
RUN jupyter notebook --generate-config --allow-root && \
    echo "c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py && \
    echo "c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:3379fd89793c:4dfb6fd74c64a436b43f30dd33e9a3a68433ce52'" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py && \
    echo "c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py && \
    echo "c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py && \
    echo "c.NotebookApp.port = 8765" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Comment: Нужно коннектится по ip:порт хоста, на котором установлен контейнер. Порты необходимые были прокинуты из контейнера?

Comment: Добрый день, @ASTyurin. Да, прокинуты. Коннект происходит, я вижу веб-интерфейс Jupyter, запущенного в контейнере. Проблема в том, что от меня требуют логин и пароль, которые мне не известны. При запуске Jupyter на ПК в консоли отображается token, который я могу использовать вместо пароля. Но приз запуске Jupyter в контейнере в консоли token не отображается. То есть передо мной запрос пароля и что туда вводить не понятно.

Comment: docker logs container_jupiter_id_or_name попробуй

Comment: Команда `docker logs 50951bff15f7` выдала ссылку `Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret`, а дальше всё тоже самое. Нашёл указанный файл. В Винде это `AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\notebook_cookie_secret`. В файле лежит только код: `tNsgsKTMkpXKBT4bxfge043GAsCHwfyIDsJZmVJcOdo=` Я было подумал, что это token, но нет. Вместо пароля он не подходит и по длине немного короче токена. В общем нужен либо пароль по умолчанию, если таковой есть, либо способ добраться до jupyter_notebook_config.py внутри контейнера.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker exec -it  id_or_name_container cat /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
```

или

```
docker exec -it id_or_name_container bash
cat /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: .@ASTyurin. Спасибо, я, по крайней мере попал внутрь контейнера и смог прочитать содержимое файла в нём. Но это мне ничего не даёт. Как я уже писал, код который содержится в notebook_cookie_secret не является токеном и не позволяет авторизоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Копируешь файл jupyter_notebook_config.py из контейнера себе на хост:

docker cp <container-name>:/root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py .

(не забудь точку в конце)

Открываешь скопированный файл, в конце будет строчка с паролем - удаляешь/закомменчиваешь эту строчку.
Копируешь файл обратно в контейнер:

docker cp jupyter_notebook_config.py <container-name>:/root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

Останавливаешь контейнер:

docker stop <container-name>

Запускаешь снова:

docker start <container-name>

Заходишь в его логи:

docker logs <container-name>

Там увидишь токен.

Открываешь в браузере:
[http://127.0.0.1:8080/?token=тут_твой_токен](http://127.0.0.1:8080/?token=%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82_%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD)
ну или вместо 8080 тот порт на который ты настроил контейнер.